# is there a way to force the order of children in an object literal?

Tags: jquery, arrays, object, soap

I am having trouble I am storing children (variables, arrays and objects) inside an object literal using jQuery.

```
var LoginVO = LoginVO || {};
```

(function($) {

```
LoginVO.username = '';
LoginVO.password = '';
LoginVO.loginDate = '';
LoginVO.userId = '';

LoginVO.authenticated = false;
LoginVO.accountNonExpired = false;
LoginVO.accountNonLocked = false;
LoginVO.credentialsNonExpired = false;
LoginVO.enabled = false;
LoginVO.salt = '';

LoginVO.timeOfLastWebServiceCall = '';
LoginVO.timeOfLastRawHttpCall = '';

LoginVO.remoteAddress = '';
LoginVO.sessionId = '';
```

})(jQuery);

When called I then stuff these objects into a model Object. So later on I ca referewnce or manipulate this child

```
modelLocator.Login.sessionId = ;1234';
```

Then at certain times in the application I need to update these children. Then I need to assemble them in to an XML string to pass back to the server in a soap envelope. However the Soap message has to be in a specific order. I have defined the objects children in the order that it appears in the xsd. The problem I am having as I do my for loop I am getting the children out of order. I can't alter the back end or the xsd, and I can't change the transport from SOAP to something else. Can someone suggest a way to order the children either on creation, or when I do the for loop to control the order of how the children get added?

Thanks for your time

Jeff

Comment: Object properties are supposed to be unordered. If order is important, use an array with the property names in the desired order and loop through that instead.

Comment: only keys are relevant for object

Comment: Why exactly are you looping over an object literal anyway? I'd instead store an array of keys and loop over the keys in your desired order, if not storing it as an array instead of an object to begin with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Object properties are supposed to be unordered. If order is important, use an array with the property names in the desired order and loop through that instead.

```
arr_desired_order = ["username","password","loginDate", /* etc. */ ];

for (var i=0, j=arr_desired_order.length; i<j; i++) {
    var key = arr_desired_order[i],
        val = LoginVO[key];
    // do something with key and val
};
```